# Origin of 'Analytic' Geometry?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview, terminology, analytic-geometry

My impression is that the name analytic geometry, which I understand roughly to be geometry in Euclidean space using coordinates, is not used that much anymore. We would probably classify the subject as an elementary version of real algebraic geometry these days, even though it's often absorbed into a course on multi-variable calculus. My question is, who coined the term 'analytic geometry'? And what was the sense in which they were using the word 'analytic'? If you know, it would be useful to have some detail on the meaning of the word in this mathematical context rather than philosophical generalities on the 'analytic-synthetic distinction.'

Comment: Jeff Miller has an [excellent webpage](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/a/) dedicated precisely to this sort of questions.

Comment: ... with a 1709 book as the first appearance.

Comment: Although it's already been answered in the comments, I'll mention this question seems better for [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Analytic geometry is not a part of algebraic geometry since it also treats the sets (in $R^n$ or in $C^n$) determined by transcendental equations.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Fair enough. I wonder if it was like that in the 17th century? It seems to me that in most conceptions, it deals with definable sets in some fairly restrictive structures. It's from that perspective that the geometry doesn't seem very 'analytic' from a present-day perspective.

Comment: They studied plenty of transcendental curves in 17th: cycloids and other trochoids, all sorts of spirals, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves#Transcendental_curves Almost all these curves were studied in 17th century, by analytic geometry.

Comment: "Analytic geometry" is also a modern research subject, as you can discover by looking to Zentralblatt (free) or Mathscinet (by subscription). But nowadays it is understood as the study of zero sets of transcendental analytic functions, to distinguish it from algebraic geometry.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Indeed that's true. However, cycloids and such are still very restrictive compared what the we would regard as analytic geometry now. According to the nice webpage mentioned above, Viete used 'analytic art' to refer to algebra. This might add credence to my initial guess that 17th C people thought of analytic geometry as algebraic geometry of some sort. Incidentally, identification of algebraic functions with polynomials (or rational functions) might also be a relatively recent convention.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis means breaking apart; taking something complex and decomposing it into simpler constituents.

This is associated with "working backwards": starting with a complicated result and finding simpler ones from which it follows. The Greeks used "analysis" in this sense in mathematics. In this process one assumes a sought result as if it was given, and works "backwards" to uncover from which simpler things it can be derived, with the intention of then reversing the steps to give a direct synthetic (synthesis = putting together) proof of the sought result.

In the 17th century, "analysis" came to mean "working with x" so to speak, because when we call a sought quantity x and start manipulating it in equations then we are indeed treating the sought as if it was known, which is exactly the classical meaning of analysis.

With the advent of calculus, since "analysis" meant "working with x" it also became associated with "working with f(x)", and hence we get analysis in today's sense of real analysis.